# why the method showStatus() does not work inside init() method of Applet?

Tags: java

i called the showStatus() method to write in status bar of my applet inside the init() method .
but it does not work since there is no error but it does not show any status i passed to showStatus();
but it works when i use showStatus() method inside paint() method.
here is my code....

```
import java.awt.*;

import java.applet.*;

import java.util.*;

public class MyApplet extends Applet

{   


public void init()
{   

    super.showStatus("God Bless You !");

}
public void start()
{ 
    setBackground(Color.black);         
}
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    Font f =new Font("Comic Sans MS",Font.ITALIC,26);
    g.setFont(f);
    g.setColor(Color. white);
    g.drawString("Nature Mother !",100,100);

}
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the code which calls the init(), paint methods etc, this class?

Comment: this is a applet java programme and we don't call the methods init(), paint() these are called by the browser during the execution by browser

Comment: What happens if you move the showStatus call into the start() method?

Comment: Same behaviour showStatus() still doesn't work